# JQuery each() function to submit form with confirm

Tags: jquery, each, confirm

I'm trying to do a confirm dialog using jquery, the form get submitted, but it didn't do the if condition, I had a form `.table` which contain multiple `.profit` table. When submit I want it check each salePrice and cost in`.profit` table column, `if cost > salePrice`, don't submit, else submit.

The problem is the page always alert the confirm window, I don't know why.
this is what I got:

```
$(".table").submit(function(event) {
  $('.salePrice').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this).parents('.profit');
  var cost = $table.find('.cost').val();
    if( $( this ).val() < cost ) {
      if(confirm("cost is larger than salePrice, are you sure？")){
          result = true;
          return false;
        } else {
          result = false;
          return false;
        }
    }
 });
 if (result) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
 }});
```

If the user clicks confirm it would check weather submit the form or not. I hope this makes sense. thanks.

HTML in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6jjhmb7L/1/

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: can you share in jsbin or jsfiddle ??

Comment: THX! I write it in jsfiddle.

Comment: demo is missing jquery dependency...look at error thrown

Comment: **[Your code Works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6jjhmb7L/4/)**. Could you elaborate what's wrong or how to replicate it?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao your link throws error , doesn't work for me

Comment: @charlietfl May I know what error please?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `result is undefined` .... as per answer below. All I did was click OK, nothing else

Comment: @charlietfl The demo above just shows whether the validation is happening properly or not.. The `confirm` dialog only shows when the validation is valid.. I just copy pasted OP's code to see if it's fine or not.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try `parseInt` and add handler,then fix!

```
$(".table").submit(function(event) {
var isOK = true, r = false;

$('.salePrice').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this).parents('.profit');

  var cost = $table.find('.cost').val();

    if (parseInt ($(this).val (), 10) < parseInt (cost, 10)) {
      if (!r) r = confirm ("cost is larger than salePrice, are you sure？");
      isOK = isOK & r;
    }
});

if (isOK) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is interpreting the values as strings (for example: "4.99") and the comparison is happening on the string values, so it is an alpha comparison instead of a numerical comparison. Try integrating `parseInt`. Also, I think your logic is reversed in the last if statement, and I had a problem when running it because of 'result' not being defined. Try this:

```
$(".table").submit(function(event) {
  var result = true;
  $('.salePrice').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this).parents('.profit');
  var cost = parseInt($table.find('.cost').val());
  var price = parseInt($( this ).val());
    if( price < cost ) {
       if(confirm("cost is larger than salePrice, are you sure？")){
          result = true;
          return false;
        } else {
          result = false;
          return false;
        }
    }
 });
 if (!result) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
 }
 });
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/xtch7hg8/5/

Comment: Weird.. code Works as expected in jsfiddle but not my developing area. I just wondering, in each() function, no matter what doing before, the result always get false in my example?

Comment: That's strange. Is there a variable called "result" defined somewhere else in your code? Also, do you have a test server where we can see the code malfunctioning?